# How do I change the default permission of file created by myself?

Tags: linux

```
[root@ test_project]$ touch test.txt
[root@ test_project]$ ll test.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  0 2011-08-03 13:57 test.txt
```

Currently it seems to be `664`,how can I change it to `700`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [umask](http://linux.die.net/man/1/umask) command to change the file creation mask. This though only masks bits. If the application creating the file does not request a bit to be set then umask wont set it. With a `umask 077` then files will generally be created `600` and directories `700`

You can set your default umask in your $HOME/.profile

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `umask`

```
sente@oslo: $ umask
0022
sente@oslo: $ umask -S
u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx

sente@oslo: $ touch foo
sente@oslo: $ ls -l foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 sente pg2662512 0 2011-08-02 23:13 foo

sente@oslo: $ umask -S u=rwx,g=,o=
u=rwx,g=,o=

sente@oslo: $ touch bar
sente@oslo: $ ls -l bar
-rw------- 1 sente pg2662512 0 2011-08-02 23:13 bar
```

I think you'll need to chmod u+x still.

`sente@oslo: $ help umask`:

```
umask: umask [-p] [-S] [mode]
    The user file-creation mask is set to MODE.  If MODE is omitted, or if
    `-S' is supplied, the current value of the mask is printed.  The `-S'
    option makes the output symbolic; otherwise an octal number is output.
    If `-p' is supplied, and MODE is omitted, the output is in a form
    that may be used as input.  If MODE begins with a digit, it is
    interpreted as an octal number, otherwise it is a symbolic mode string
    like that accepted by chmod(1).
```